# InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository: Factory method threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASSWORD

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am using spring-boot with spring-security and OAuth2 authorization in my standalone application, but I have an unexpected error, who I can't fix. This is associated with `ClientRegistrationRepository` and my factory method. I tried to make own implementation of this interface, but I had same problem. Details:

Libraries:
 - spring-boot-starter: **2.1.9.RELEASE**
 - spring-security-core, spring-security-web, spring-security-config, spring-security-oauth2-client, spring-security-oauth2-jose: **5.2.0.RELEASE**

Stacktrace: [here](https://gist.github.com/kacperduras/8d270f35554b72591f5f4841ff3fbbf0)
Snippet: [here](https://gist.github.com/kacperduras/a7b9202b51bcc2336cc800a511287a21)

That's all. Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the library issue: I found there's the following code in the ClientRegistration class:

```
  } else if (AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD.equals(this.authorizationGrantType)) {
            this.validatePasswordGrantType();
```

but AuthorizationGrantType class doesn't contain such field.
I used 5.1.6.RELEASE and it helped.

Comment: It works, thanks! I created the issue in official repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7545